# Detectar si la tecla de la barra espaciadora se pulsó

Tags: javascript

Quiero que con un `.addEventListener()` se detecte si se presionó la tecla espacio.

No tengo idea de cómo hacerlo. Probé colocando:

```
.addEventListener('space', function() { ... })
```

Pero no funcionó.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Dónde has colocado ese código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes colocar un manipulador del evento [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) para detectar cuándo se pulsa una tecla en cualquier elemento del DOM.

Si lo haces a nivel de `window` entonces lo detectarás estés en el elemento que estés del documento.

Puedes detectar la tecla pulsada a través de la propiedad `key` o `code`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (evento) => {
  /* El código "Space" representa la pulsación de la barra espaciadora */
  if (evento.code == "Space") {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = "Pulsada barra espaciadora";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
});
```